# Create site backup on WebDeploy

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I want to enable backups on my asp.net mvc site, so on webdeploys I have a clean backup. I followed this [guide](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups) and ran the BackupScripts.ps1 and then enabled the backup for my site. Then I validated this by running "Get-BackupSettings -SiteName mysite"

```
CanSetNumberOfBackups       : False
Enabled                     : True
BackupPath                  : C:\temp\backups\{siteName}_snapshots
CanSetContinueSyncOnFailure : False
CanAddExcludedProviders     : False
CanSetEnabled               : False
ExcludedProviders           : {appPoolEnable32Bit, appHostAuthOverride, appPoolNetFx, appPoolPipeline...}
ContinueSyncOnFailure       : True
SiteName                    : mysite
NumberOfBackups             : 10
```

Now I'm expecting that without changing anything in the VS publish profiles the server would create backup on every webDeploy, but it isnt doing that. The wmsvc logs do not mention anything about the backups and the publish succeeds. I restarted the MsDepSvc and WMSvc as well. I also validate my backup setting by running this following command and the back was successful y created.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:backupManager -dest:backupManager=mysite
```

Any suggestions? FYI, im using webdeploy 3.5

Answer (score 1):

ok it turns out I had to make a change on the publishing profile.

```
 <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
```